# Add new attributes for rendering?

Tags: theming, 8

In Drupal 8, how can you add new attributes to be rendered into the twig file?

I want to provide a region.html.twig that can be extended for subtheming.

So, I want the default to be:

```
{%
  set wrapper_classes = [
    'region',
    'region-' ~ region|clean_class,
    'container',
    'container--100',
  ]
%}

{%
  set outer_column_classes = [
    'container__col',
  ]
%}

{%
  set inner_column_classes = [
    'container__inner',
  ]
%}

<div{{ wrapper_attributes.addClass(wrapper_classes) }}>
  <div{{ outer_column_attributes.addClass(outer_column_classes) }}>
    <div{{ inner_column_attributes.addClass(inner_column_classes) }}>
      {% block content %}
        {{ content }}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Simply making them arrays or strings as you would in D7 doesn't work - they never reach the twig template.

I noticed that Bartik uses the Attribute class to create new/empty Attributes. Is this kosher to do, exactly?

```
use Drupal\Core\Template\Attribute;

function mytheme_preprocess_region(&$variables) {
  $variables['wrapper_attributes'] = new Attribute();
  $variables['outer_column_attributes'] = new Attribute();
  $variables['inner_column_attributes'] = new Attribute();
}
```

When I do that, my new attributes appear and are rendered in the template. Is this even worth doing, or is it a lot more trouble to extend templates and manipulate them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is exactly about this issue:

> **Allow instantiating Attribute objects within Twig**
>
> **Problem/Motivation**
>
> Sometimes you have an array of attributes and it would be nice if you
>   could addClass, removeClass, setAttribute, etc. rather than trying to
>   do array manipulation.
>
> **Proposed resolution**
>
> Add a function to our Twig extension to allow creating an Attribute
>   object from an array of attributes.

Issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2616756

And the change record for **8.3.x**:

```
{% set my_attribute = create_attribute() %}
{%
  set my_classes = [
    'kittens',
    'llamas',
    'puppies',
  ]
%}
<div{{ my_attribute.addClass(my_classes).addAttribute('id', 'myUniqueId') }}>
  {{ content }}
</div>
<div{{ create_attribute({'class': ['region', 'region--header']}) }}>
  {{ content }}
</div>
```

https://www.drupal.org/node/2818293